Unity2D Camera do not match output properties error

Camera do not match the output properties error appears in the camera stack. It seems to be an error caused by the resolution of Main Camera and UI Camera.
Pushing the Fix button in the in-game fixes the problem, but the same problem repeats when it comes back to Editor.
If the Game resolution setting is set to 9:16 Portrait, it will work normally, but for other resolutions (ex. Iphone 11), this error occurs.
Any ideas?
I've tried everything that came out of this link.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-camera-not-sent-on-stream.1490065/

I had the same problem. I realize that I changed the render output, but forgot to set to null again.
